# Acceder a un array de array y me devuelve los resultados en otra array de resultados que creo yo mediante push

Tags: javascript

Tengo un ejercicio de Javascript para hacer y desde ayer estoy intentando solucionar la parte 2. A ver si ven en que parte estoy cometiendo errores.

El enunciado, función aperturas, me pide que recorrer un array dentro de otro array ([[0, 0, 3, 0], [1, 2, 4, 5], [0, 0, -1]], 3). Cada numero en el array equivale a los minutos que llegaron a clase los alumnos. Si llegaron la misma cantidad de alumnos o mas con tiempo de sobra ( serian los números negativos o 0) la clase abrio (True) sino no abre(false).

Tengo que acceder a un array de array y me devuelve los resultados en otra array de resultados que creo yo mediante push. ej: aperturas([[0, 0, 3, 0], [1, 2, 4, 5], [0, 0, -1]], 3), tendría que devolver resultados [ true, false, true ]. Nose si fue claro con la explicación.

---

Una profesora de programación, cansada de que los estudiantes lleguen tarde, decidió que va a cancelar la clase si hay pocos presentes.

Ella representa a los ingresos de los estudiantes como un array de tiempos de llegada tarde, en minutos. Por ejemplo, si un estudiante llegó 10 minutos tarde, otro 5 minutos antes de hora, otro 3 minutos tarde, y otro puntual, lo representa así:

var ingresosDelLunes = [10, -5, 3, 0];
Con esta información y la cantidad de estudiantes mínimos para abrir el curso, la profesora quiere saber si la clase se abre. Por ejemplo, suponiendo que la cantidad minima de estudiantes para que la clase se de es 2, el curso del lunes se abre, porque hubo un estudiante que llegó puntual y un estudiante que llegó temprano.

seAbre(ingresosDelLunes, 2)
true
Pero si la cantidad mínima fuera 3, la clase no se abriria:

seAbre(ingresosDelLunes, 3)
false
Escribi las siguientes funciones:

seAbre, que dice si se hace una clase dado el array de ingresos
aperturas, que toma un array con los arrays de ingresos de varios días, y la cantidad mínima de estudiante, y diga que dias se abrió y que días no. Por ejemplo:
aperturas([ingresosDelLunes, ingresosDelMartes, ingresosDelMiercoles], 2)
[true, false, false]

```js
  function aperturas(array, alumnos) {
    var resultado = [];
    var alumnosLlegada = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
        if (array[i][j] <=0) {
        alumnosLlegada++
        }
      }
      if (alumnosLlegada >= alumnos) {
        resultado.push(true)
      }else {
        resultado.push(false)
      }
    }
    return resultado
  }
```

Comment: ¿Qué problema has encontrado?¿Qué es lo que pasa con tu código?

Comment: que la seugnda parte de la funcion aperturas, no funciona..

Comment: puedes colocar lo que quieres que haga , el enunciado lo debes comprender tu , nosotros tratamos solucionar tu error, no el del enunciando

Comment: añade esto a la pregunta , editala para que cpmprendamos , la mayoria de los usuarios lee la pregunta y luego intenta ayudarte,

Comment: si el seAbre funciona no lo colocas , basate solo en el que tienes el error por que presta a confusion

Comment: ahi intente arreglarlo, el tema es que para entender el punto dos hayque ver el punto 1

Comment: Una consulta el "array" de aperturas es el array "seAbre"?

Comment: estoy con el mismo ejercicio y tengo problemas. Podrías mostrar lo que hiciste para resolver la primera parte? Gracias.

Comment: cómo hiciste la primera parte del ejercicio? la que te indica hacer la función seAbre?

Answer (score 2):

Tu script funciona correctamente, tu único problema es dónde declaras tu variable:

```
function aperturas(array, alumnos) {
    var resultado = [];
    //antes estaba aqui y  se quedaba con el valor de la ultima iteracion
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        //debes inicializar la variable cada vez que cambiar de array
        var alumnosLlegada = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            if (array[i][j] <=0) {
                alumnosLlegada++
            }
        }
        if (alumnosLlegada >= alumnos) {
            resultado.push(true)
        }else {
            resultado.push(false)
        }
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

Comment: @FernandoColom: Favor de leer [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @FernandoColom si esta respuesta resolvió tu problema, no dejes un comentario dando las gracias, márcala como aceptada pulsando en la parte superior izquierda de la respuesta.